# Seeking Elevation Data for Scotland?

Tags: data, vector, dem, elevation, scotland

I have been searching for quality elevation data for the entire Scotland but I have not succeeded yet.

Do you know where to get the data in Raster or Vector formats?

Accuracy is very important as I intend to compare with other data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are in academia then the obvious place to go would be edina and [digimap](http://digimap.edina.ac.uk/digimap/home).

If you are not, then have a look here for [free](http://freegisdata.rtwilson.com/#elevation) elevation data. Of cause you could go to [OS](http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/products/terrain-50.html) the national mapping agency of the UK and get a 50m terrain model.

Answer (score 2):

Free of charge i would say:
Get either ASTER or SRTM from [earthexplorer](http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov).
Both are available at 1 arc-sec., respectively ~20m vertical rmse.