# raster topo map with gaps to DEM

Tags: raster, dem, contour, digitizing, topography

I'm trying to create a DEM from this raster map:

[image]

I managed to clean all the shapes and text. I tried to write a program which finds the curve pieces and connects them. But, I realized that it is not simple. Is there a program which takes this raster map and gives me DEM. I want to create a 3D model of this terrain.

Comment: You chose a complex task to handle. If it is a "real" area you might use free and available DEMs; depand on the resolution you need. See this [thread](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/140017/where-do-i-get-elevation-data-for-scotland)

Comment: This is a real area but it is in Turkey. I couldn't find a detailed topo map or DEM. This is an archeological site, Sagalassos. The researchers didn't reply to my emails. I just wanted to start a fun project of making a 3d reconstruction of the site.

Comment: The thread I attached deals with Scotland, but the data is global. If it is for fun project I suggest to use free data. i.e. ASTER DEM is 30 meters spatial resolution and +/- 20 meters in altitude.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. The area is 1200m x 1200m. So, I feel that 30m spatial resolution is a bit low. I will model buildings and streets. If I can complete it, the resolution will be 2m.

Comment: hard task, and not sure about accuracy. Good Luck

Comment: There are tools commonly known as Clean Contour Gaps in many GIS programs. However from your image none of them are likely to be very successful because there are far too many gaps and some of them are too wide. In fact some of what I see ('holes' for buildings, etc) would need some break lines. There's really no way to go from raster contours (at least like those) directly to a DEM. You'd first need to vectorize the raster lines, and that would take a lot of manual cleanup (the grid lines don't help).

Comment: you can get the contour of that region?  you can create a DEM with SAGA GIS and contours or points (xyz)

Comment: you need to vectorize the image, then add height at each corner and then recently you can use a program to create a DEM (for example Engauge Digitizer or other)

Answer (score 1):

I made vectorization of countours few years ago in ArcMap. There is ArcScan toolbar when I did it. Vectorization, of course, wasn't hundred per cent. You have to then manually edit some lines.

In **ArcScan toolbar** I used **Generate Features Inside Area**. You can try it if you want.